# Square Matrices

Tags: matrices

So I'm studying a few special families of square matrices, the diagonal matrices, upper triangular matrices, lower triangular matrices and symmetric matrices and I just had a few questions.

I know...

a diagonal matrix is if every nondiagonal entry is zero, $a_{ij}$=0 whenever $i$ doesn't equal $j
$.

an upper triangular matrix is if all entries below the diagonal are zero, $a_{ij}=0$ whenever $i >j$.

a lower triangular matrix is if all entries above the diagonal are zero, $a_{ij}=0$ whenever $i < j$.

symmetric if $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$ for all $i$ and $j$.

> But I was just wondering, can the diagonal matrices, upper triangular matrices, lower triangular matrices and symmetric matrices have the $0_{n\times n}$? Also I know the $I_{n\times n}$ matrix is in the diagonal matrices, but can it be in the other three types?

Comment: Both the zero matrix and the identity matrix are diagonal, upper/lower triangular, and symmetric. Check the definitions.

Comment: Just check the hypothesis

Answer (score 1):

Take for example the definition of upper triangular matrix. It's a matrix which has $a_{ij}=0$ whenever $ i>j $, but this doesn't mean that $a_{ij}\neq 0$ for $ i\le j $, it's possible to have $ a_{ij}=0$ if $ i\le j$. Then both $O_{n\times n} $ and $ I_{n\times n} $ are upper triangular matrices.

The same idea applies to the diagonal, lower triangular and symmetric matrices.